# pandas - figuring out how many rows needed to reach a pct

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas series of number, I would like to know how many of these numbers I need to reach 80% of the value of the series (given that the serie is ordered, and taking the biggest number first).

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract that number using `cumsum`

```
df = pd.Series(list(reversed(range(1,10))))
sum = df.cumsum()
list(sum)
#[9, 17, 24, 30, 35, 39, 42, 44, 45]
list(sum[sum > 0.8 * max(sum)].index)[0]+1
#6
```